# wsdl:import issue with custom binding in CXF

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd, cxf

I am not able to get a custom binding work for an XSD imported in a WSDL using `wsdl:import` tag.

I guess `wsdl:type` and `xsd:import` is the best way to import schema from an XSD but I am in need of a solution where I do not have to change the WSDL.

I am using CXF for generating the artifacts from the WSDL and it works fine when I do not use any custom binding but since my requirement is to change the name of the classes defined in the schema I intend to use a custom binding.

WSDL contains:

```
<definitions name="MMMWS" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:xmmmd="http://xyz.com/abcdata"
    xmlns:xmmms="http://xyz.com/abcservice"
    targetNamespace="http://xyz.com/abcservice">

    <import namespace="http://xyz.com/abcdata" location="abcdata.xsd"/>

.....
```

Binding file (.xjb) contains:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.0"
        xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
        xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
        jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc"
        schemaLocation="abcdata.xsd">

.....
```

The error I get is:

```
[ERROR] "file:abcdata.xsd" is not a part of this compilation. Is this a mistake for "file:abcdata.xjb"?
[ERROR] at line 7 column 51 of schema file:abcdata.xjb
```